# Find previous node in tree

Tags: r, tree, treenode

I've got the following code:

```
df <- read.table(text='verkoop          V621  
verkoopcode      V62123  
verkoopcodenaam  V6212355  
verkoopdatum     V621335  
verkoopdatumchar V62133526  
verkooppr        V6216  
verkoopprijs     V62162  
verkoopsafdeling V621213452  
verkoopsartikel  V62126324') 

# use igraph package
require(igraph)

# create adjacency matrix 
adj <- nchar(sapply(df$V1, gsub, x=df$V1, replacement=''))
adj[!sapply(df$V1, grepl, x=df$V1)] <- 0

# name adjecency matrix 
colnames(adj) <- df$V2

# original graph
gr <- graph.adjacency(adj, mode='directed', weighted=TRUE)

layout(matrix(1:2, ncol=2))
plot(gr)

# minimum spanning tree 
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(gr)
shortest.paths(mst, to="V621", weights=rep(1, ecount(mst)))
```

Now I get for every node the depth in the tree. I want to determine now which node comes before a specific node. For example, for 'verkoopdatumchar' I want to find 'verkoopdatum'.

Comment: So are you just wanting to find the child of each node? If so, look at `neighbors`

Comment: I can't find that function, which is its package?

Comment: Its in `igraph`. As in, `V(mst)[neighbors(mst, v="V62133526", mode="out")]`